# Webpack, html-webpack-plugin, Error: Child compilation failed

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I 've got a problem with my webpack configuration. After implementing html-webpack-plugin I got an Error, there's whole error stack from generated `index.html`.

Error Stack:
Html Webpack Plugin:

```
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename index.html:
  Error: Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename index.html
```

- compiler.js:76 
  [Pre-build]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16
- Compiler.js:291 Compiler.
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:291:10
- Compiler.js:494 
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:494:13
- Tapable.js:138 next
  [Pre-build]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:138:11
- CachePlugin.js:62 Compiler.
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5
- Tapable.js:142 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [Pre-build]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:142:13
- Compiler.js:491 
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:491:10
- Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [Pre-build]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46
- Compilation.js:645 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:645:19
- Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [Pre-build]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46
- Compilation.js:636 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:636:11
- Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [Pre-build]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46
- Compilation.js:631 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:631:10
- Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [Pre-build]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46
- Compilation.js:627 sealPart2
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:627:9
- Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
  [Pre-build]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46
- Compilation.js:575 Compilation.seal
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:575:8
- Compiler.js:488 
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:488:16
- Tapable.js:225 
  [Pre-build]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:225:11
- Compilation.js:477 _addModuleChain
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:477:11
- Compilation.js:448 processModuleDependencies.err
  [Pre-build]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:448:13
- next_tick.js:73 _combinedTickCallback
  internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7
- next_tick.js:104 process._tickCallback
  internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9

My webpack configuration code:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path');


var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'),
    ExtractTextWebpackPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),

const sourcePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
const staticPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './static');

module.exports = function (env) {

    const nodeEnv = env && env.prod ? 'production' : 'development';
    const isProd = nodeEnv === 'production';

    const postcssLoader = {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
            plugins: function () {
                return [
                    require('autoprefixer')
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    const plugins = [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: Infinity,
            filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'
        }),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: nodeEnv,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html',
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true
            },
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
        })
    ];

    if(isProd) {
        plugins.push(
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                minimize: true,
                debug: false
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compress: {
                    warnings: false,
                    screw_ie8: true,
                    conditionals: true,
                    unused: true,
                    comparisons: true,
                    sequences: true,
                    dead_code: true,
                    evaluate: true,
                    if_return: true,
                    join_vars: true,
                },
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                },
            })
        );
    } else {
        plugins.push(
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
        );
    }

    return {
        devtool: isProd? 'source-map' : 'eval',
        context: sourcePath,

        entry: {
            app: './app/entry.ts',
            vendor: './app/vendor.ts'
        },

        output: {
            path: staticPath,
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        query: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]'
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'postcss-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'postcss-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        'ts-loader'
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },

        resolve: {
            alias: {
                Public: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/public'),
                Style: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/styles')
            },
            extensions: ['.ts','.js', '.html'],
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                sourcePath
            ]
        },

        plugins,

        performance: isProd && {
            maxAssetSize: 100,
            maxEntrypointSize: 300,
            hints: 'warning'
        },

        stats: {
            colors: {
                green: '\u001b[32m'
            }
        },

        devServer: {
            contentBase: './src',
            historyApiFallback: true,
            port: 3000,
            compress: isProd,
            inline: !isProd,
            hot: !isProd,
            stats: {
                assets: true,
                children: false,
                chunks: false,
                hash: false,
                modules: false,
                publicPath: false,
                timings: true,
                version: false,
                warnings: true,
                color: {
                    green: '\u001b[32m'
                }
            },
        }
    };
};
```

I couldn't find any source of that Error, maybe I am little bit tired, but I would like to finish it up, so I hope for your help guys.

Maybe should I use some `raw-loader` to load `.html`(?), which does not make me happy.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is indeed the `file-loader`, because it simply copies the file over. By the time `html-webpack-plugin` tries to write `index.html` it has already been written by `file-loader`, hence resulting in a conflict.

There are several ways to resolve that issue, depending on what your needs are.

You could use [`html-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader) for your HTML, although if you expect your imported HTML to simply be copied, it isn't the correct choice. To be clear, by the imported HTML I don't mean the template used by the `html-webpack-plugin`.

If you want to keep using the `file-loader` for your other HTML files, you can exclude the `index.html` so `html-webpack-plugin` falls back to its default loader. `require.resolve` works like `require` but gives you the full path of the module instead of its content.

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, require.resolve('./index.html')],
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
            name: '[name].[ext]'
        },
    },
},
```

When no loader matches the template, the `html-webpack-plugin` uses an [`ejs` loader as a fallback](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md#1-dont-set-any-loader). If you don't need any loader for `.html` files, you could remove the rule entirely and it would work just fine. That is rather unlikely, otherwise you wouldn't have a `.html` rule in the first place, but this also means you can use the `.ejs` extension to not apply the `.html` rule, as all HTML is valid [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs). You would rename `index.html` to `index.ejs` and change your plugin configuration accordingly:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.ejs',
    minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
    },
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
})
```

Comment: Great answer and explanation! I really appreciate your post, and I made decision to stay with `html-webpack-plugin`, and delete `html-loader`, as long as I do single-site. Real thanks, things are much more clear to me now. =)

Answer (score 4):

I had to upgrade my node version. then the issue is fixed.

upgrade to latest node version(ubuntu)

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo n latest
```

to check the version

```
node -v
```

you might need to restart your terminal to see the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to my problem was updating node version.

Comment: 12 to  ta 14. using nvm

Answer (score 1):

For my case I had the template file name misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be not ordinary case, but for me, problem was caused by symbol **"!"** in the path. After I moved all content to the folder without **"!"** then the error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

delete node modules package then run npm install all package install then npm start the same problem are face but this process to run solve the problem so this solution is useful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31229513)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue few minutes ago  and I switched to a stable version of node to solve it. It worked

> ```
> sudo npm cache clean -f
>
> sudo npm install -g n
>
> sudo n stable
> ```

Answer (score -3):

Simple Updated Node JS Version. And use

```
npm i
```

this will update your all libraries
This method works for me you can also try