# Every time i run npx create-react-app my-app it shows this html webpack error after npm start

Tags: reactjs

Html Webpack Plugin:
Error: Child compilation failed:
Module parse failed: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined

- Parser.js:2409 Function.parse
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/Parser.js:2409:22
- Parser.js:2273 Parser.parse
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/Parser.js:2273:17
- NormalModule.js:482
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:482:32
- NormalModule.js:358
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
- LoaderRunner.js:373
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
- LoaderRunner.js:214 iterateNormalLoaders
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10
- LoaderRunner.js:221 iterateNormalLoaders
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10
- LoaderRunner.js:236
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
- LoaderRunner.js:130 runSyncOrAsync
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
- ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
- File was processed with these loaders:
- - ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js
- You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
- Parser.js:2409 Function.parse
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/Parser.js:2409:22
- Parser.js:2273 Parser.parse
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/Parser.js:2273:17
- NormalModule.js:482
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:482:32
- NormalModule.js:358
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
- LoaderRunner.js:373
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
- LoaderRunner.js:214 iterateNormalLoaders
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10
- LoaderRunner.js:221 iterateNormalLoaders
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10
- LoaderRunner.js:236
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
- LoaderRunner.js:130 runSyncOrAsync
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11
- LoaderRunner.js:232 iterateNormalLoaders
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2
- NormalModule.js:469 handleParseError
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:469:19
- NormalModule.js:503
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
- NormalModule.js:358
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
- LoaderRunner.js:373
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
- LoaderRunner.js:214 iterateNormalLoaders
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10
- LoaderRunner.js:221 iterateNormalLoaders
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10
- LoaderRunner.js:236
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
- LoaderRunner.js:130 runSyncOrAsync
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11
- LoaderRunner.js:232 iterateNormalLoaders
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2
- LoaderRunner.js:205 Array.
  [client]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4
- child-compiler.js:131
  [client]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:131:18
- Compiler.js:343
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11
- Compiler.js:681
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [client]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compiler.js:678
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [client]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1423
  [client]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35

Comment: see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494794/webpack-html-webpack-plugin-error-child-compilation-failed) it might be helpful for you.

Comment: yes i tried many things but nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this Issue to downgrade react-scripts package with 4.0.1 maybe this answer will help someone someday